# How to create, access and edit csv documents on internet using java

Tags: java, csv, file-upload, https

I'm creating a game in java and I want to store the scores on a csv file on the internet so different people who download the game and can compete for a high score.

How can I:

1. create a csv file and give it a url
2. make the csv file editable only through my program
3. access data from that csv file given its url
4. edit that csv file given its url

thanks!

Edit: Sorry I don't have code to post as I don't even know where to start. I tried looking it up but only find things relating to files that have already been downloaded

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Mureinik i have no idea where to even start. I have tried looking it up but all I'm finding is for files that are saved in my hard disk.

Comment: I think your questions will not be answered until you decide on the architecture of your game, and how the files will be saved, which format they will have and so on

Comment: @NationBoneless the game has already been made and I did say that I'm trying to store the info as a csv file.

Comment: 1. There a different Java Libraries out there for writing to a csv-file. Alternatively you can just use plain java, as a csv is just text. Then to "give it a url", you would need a server of some sort, on which the file is saved and accessible from the internet. Also a domain pointing to that server could be useful. You could start arguing, that a csv might not be the most efficient way to store game data, but I guess that's alright for now

Comment: 2. Then you could create an upload point on your server, or a connection like ssh or webDav, which you could then protect via a user and password, so that you are the only one in control of that file

Comment: 3. This is easy, once the file is on the server and accessible via a url. You can just download it, or create another site on your server, which displays the file in a nice way, for you to read it (like json)

Comment: 4. This would be the hardest part, as you will have to deal with multiple instances of your game possibly trying to save at the same time, therefore you would have to implement a system to synchronize saves.

Comment: You need "somewhere" to store data.  Where have you decided to store it?   "On the internet" is not sufficiently specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. run a server (probably in java) on a computer that is always on, and have the client (the game) connect to it via a socket. Use something like freedns or noip to get the URL.
2. have the client report its score to the server, and the server will write it to a csv file.
3. have the client request scores from the server
4. this is solved by 2

sign up for freeDNS [here](https://freedns.afraid.org/)

use this tutorial for sockets: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEDV0WlwXTs)

if you don't have a computer that is always on, try using [amazon AWS free](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

This is probably a bit more complicated than what you wanted, but it's the only way I've heard of.